# How to enable code coverage (TFS) for only some of the builds

Tags: tfs, code-coverage

I'm using TFS2008 - soon to move to TFS2010

I want run code coverage for as part of my nightly builds. Since it adds some overhead I don't want it to run on my dev machine or as part of the CI build.

Is there a way to run code coverage only on my nightly builds?

The only way I'm aware is having two *.testconfig* files one for each build - and I'm wondering if anyone has tried doing that. If I choose this path how do I define while *testconfig* file to use locally?

Comment: What test runner are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. 
You can have different Build Definitions (one for CI & one for Nightly), and then simply set Code Coverage to the latter.
Separating the builds with different Definitions is in any case a good idea. 
Each build has different targets/requirements anyway (what they do with WorkItems, what Tests they do, what DBs-WebApps they deploy, what they email to whom etc).

Comment: The only problem is that TFS build definition does not effect the code coverage - this is part of the test configuration.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to also have different testsettings per build definition. My testrunner is NUnit, I could show you how we 're doing it with it.

Comment: That's explains your answer. In MSTest the coverage is determined by a file at the solution .testconfig I'm trying to avoid having two of those.

Comment: Why try avoiding it? You have clearly two distinct test configurations. Are you for example fearing/expecting that you 'll maintain those frequently?